# check one of the two checkboxes with the same class

Tags: semantic-ui

I just started using semantic UI and I have a silly question.
I have two checkboxes with class name as "ui toggle checkbox". 
When page is loaded, I want to check these checkboxes based on some condition.

```
  <div class="ui toggle checkbox " id="ssl">
            <input type="checkbox" name="SSL" >
            <label>3</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <label>Web Service Request Logging : </label>
        <div class="ui toggle checkbox" id="wsl">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Logging" >
            <label>7</label>
        </div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wsl = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var ssl = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    alert(wsl);
    alert(ssl);

    if (ssl <3) {
        $('.ui.toggle.checkbox').checkbox('check');
    }

    if (wsl <7) {
        $('.ui.toggle.checkbox').checkbox('check');
    }     

});
```

The problem is, When the number is say 5, it checks both the check boxes. How to differentiate between the two checkboxes with the same class in semanti UI.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the id attribute and get the checkbox input element and toggle the checked attribute with .attr() like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wsl = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var ssl = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    alert(wsl);
    alert(ssl);

    if (ssl <3) {
        $('#ssl input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    }

    if (wsl <7) {
        $('#wsl input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    }     

});
```